# Design the data structure to query least common multiple of a submatrix efficiently

Tags: algorithm

The question comes from an interview. There is an NxN matrix with integers, N might be above 10^4. The question is how to design an assistant data structure to efficiently get the least common multiple of any sub-rectangle matrix of the NxN matrix. The space used should not exceed 2xNxN or 3xNxN, I cannot  remember it clearly, while let's not limit the space too rigorously.

Comment: It's not at all clear what *2xNxN* is supposed to mean

Comment: @NiklasB. 2x(original space)

Comment: a range tree (2D segment tree if you so want) can do that. It's not simple though, I can't really imagine they would expect someone to come up with this without already knowing it

Answer (score 2):

I think [Segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) will help. Let consider an easier problem, where you are given an array `A[N]` with `N` integers, than query the least common multiple of any sub-array. With segment tree, associate each node `[l, r]` with the least common multiple. Each query consts
`O(lnN)` time and the total space is about `2*N`.

For the matrix, use a 2-dimensional segment tree.  Here is a solution for [query gcd in matrix](http://www.quora.com/Algorithms/Given-a-M%2aN-matrix-we-need-to-query-the-GCD-of-numbers-in-any-given-submatrix-range-%EF%BC%88x1-y1-x2-y2%EF%BC%89-x1-y1-x2-y2-are-the-positions-of-top-left-element-and-bottom-right-element-of-submatrix-respectively-How-can-we-design-a-preprocessing-mechanism-to-accelerate-the-query-speed), which is similar to your problem.